# Matching image path inside javascript

Tags: php, regex

wget does a good job of pulling down prerequisite files, but it cannot detect image paths inside a JS file.  I need a regex to scan JS files for any image paths it finds.

These paths would generally be nested as follows:

```
$img1 = "foo/bar.png";
$img2 = 'foo/bar.jpg';
$img3 = "{'myimg':'foo/bar.png'}";
```

I need a regex which will be able to pick up the whole image path inside the quotes, but sometimes nested inside a json string, or otherwise encoded... essentially, matching a whole image path by detecting just the existence of the extension (jpg|png|gif).

Comment: What about `$path = "/foo"; $img = $path + "bar.png";`?

Comment: The regex needs to be able to detect the existence of any image.  The path is unknown, and the filename is unknown - for example we could have `/wp-content/uploads/myimage.png` or `/images/bigredbus.jpg`.  I need to be able to isolate the image paths so that I can download them.  I don't need to construct an image path, rather detect and return an image path within the JS file.

Comment: I know; I'm asking, what about paths which are built programmatically, that a regular expression can't possibly find?

Comment: Ah, sorry!  The regex just needs to be a "best fit".  I appreciate that some instances cannot be catered for (or moreso can, but will be factored in at a later stage).  For now if I can find full paths, I'll work on a path constructor at a later stage :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this pattern:

```
$pattern = '~/?(?>[^"\'/]+/)+[^"\'\s]+?\.(?>png|jpe?g|gif)\b~';
```

Comment: This is the best fit so far - thanks!  It needs to account for spaces in urls too, such as "/path/to img/foo.jpg".  Can you please edit the regex to include support for this?  Thanks.

Comment: How to format this regex so that it can work in javascript?