# Matching image path inside javascript using javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6, regex-group, regex-negation

I need a regex to scan JS files for any image paths it finds.

These paths would generally be nested as follows:

```
$img1 = "foo/bar.png";
$img2 = 'foo/bar.jpg';
$img3 = "{'myimg':'foo/bar.png'}";
```

I need a regex which will be able to pick up the whole image path inside the quotes, but sometimes nested inside a json string, or otherwise encoded... essentially, matching a whole image path by detecting just the existence of the extension (jpg|png|gif).

I have [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17111813/matching-image-path-inside-javascript) a regex that works well in php, I need one that works with javascript.

```
$pattern = '~/?+(?>[^"\'/]++/)+[^"\'\s]+?\.(?>(?>pn|jpe?)g|gif)\b~';
```

How the form of regex pattern in javascript?

Comment: maybe exclude matching the quotes `[^"']*\.(?:(?:pn|jpe?)g|gif)\b` https://regex101.com/r/750x5s/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possessive quantifiers `++` and atomic groups `(?>` are not supported in Javascript.

The updated pattern could look like this:

```
\/?(?:[^"'/]+\/)+[^"'\s]+?\.(?:(?:pn|jpe?)g|gif)\b
```

But to get those matches and if `//` in the path is also ok, you can exclude matching the quotes using a negated character class `[^"']*`  only

Note to escape the `\/` as the regex delimiters in Javscript are `/` and that you don't have to escape the `'` and `"` in the character class.

The shorter version could look like

```
[^"']+\.(?:(?:pn|jpe?)g|gif)\b
```

- `[^"']+` Match any char except `'` or `"` 1+ times
- `\.` Match a dot
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?:pn|jpe?)g` Match either png jpg or jpeg
  - `|` Or
  - `gif` Match literally
- `)\b` Close non capture group followed by a word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iUgmr3/1)

```js
const regex = /[^"']+\.(?:(?:pn|jpe?)g|gif)\b/;
[
  "foo/bar.png",
  "foo/bar.jpg",
  "{'myimg':'foo/bar.png'}"
].forEach(s => console.log(s.match(regex)[0]));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use

```js
string.match(/[^"'<>]+\.(?:png|jpe?g|gif)\b/gi)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/KRJeyd/1). Note: `g` - all occurrences, `i` - case insensitive, `<>` added to the expression to limit matching up to a tag.

**Explanation**

```php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^"'<>]+                 any character except: '"', ''', '<', '>'
                           (1 or more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    png                      'png'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    jp                       'jp'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    e?                       'e' (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    g                        'g'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    gif                      'gif'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
```